# area of the portion which is in the cone

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the area of the portion of the unit sphere that is in the cone $z\ge \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

I approached the problem like this:

I thought of the surface like this:
$\phi(x,y)$=($x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$)

And the region is: $2x^2+2y^2=1$

Am i right??

Comment: what do you mean for unit sphere?

Comment: No, you want a portion of the sphere, not of the cone. HINT: A horizontal plane would do just as well as the cone.

Comment: so z=sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} would be my region?? @TedShifrin

Comment: Yes. Do you know spherical coordinates? That gives an alternative parametrization.

Comment: will the answer be 2pi(1-1/sqrt(2))?

Comment: i've got $2\pi(1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$

Comment: post your answer then@ janmarqz

Comment: i was wrong XD.

Answer (score 1):

For a surface of the form $z = \phi(x,y)$, $(x,y) \in D$, or $z=\phi(r,\theta)$, $(r,\theta) \in D$, the formula for the area of the surface is

$${\iint}_D \sqrt{1 + \|\nabla \phi\|^2} \,dA.  $$

Of course, what "$dA$" looks like will depend on whether you are using rectangular or polar coordinates.  In this problem, if you think of $\phi$ as a function of $r$ and $\theta$, then $\|\nabla\phi\|^2$ in polar coordinates is easily to find because $\phi$ will depend only on $r$ and not on $\theta$.

I think I have done a problem just like this and it worked out fine.

An alternative is to use spherical coordinates but a disadvantage is you have to remember how to use spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

By employing ${\rm Area}=\int\int_R\sqrt{EG-F^2}dr\wedge d\theta$, take $R$ the region given by $0<r<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $0<\theta<2\pi$ to parameterize with $(r,\theta)\to(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,\sqrt{1-r^2})$ the surface, then your integral becomes $\int_0^{1/\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}dr\!\wedge\!d\theta$ which will be $2\pi(1-\frac{1}{2})$

Comment: should the radius not vary from 0 to 1/sqrt{2}??

Comment: yes, you are right :D

Comment: then the answer is 2pi(1-1/sqrt{2})